# Convert string to Date format

Tags: c#, .net, string, date, type-conversion

my string is as follows:

```
string s ="20000101";
```

I would like to convert it to Date format. How can I do it?

Comment: What is the programming language you are using?

Comment: @Jamey: good point. I am assuming C# because of the general syntax with the lowercase `string`. The request for a `Date` object implies Java, but then it should be `String`. C++ has `string`, but nothing like a `Date` or `DateTime` object.

Comment: Most of his other questions are about `C#` so it's probably a safe assumption.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming you are using C# and .Net you will want to use [DateTime.ParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parseexact.aspx) or [DateTime.TryParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparseexact.aspx).  The format string is most likely "yyyyMMdd".

```
var datestring = "20000101";

var date1 = DateTime.ParseExact(datestring, "yyyyMMdd", null);
```

or

```
DateTime dateResult;
if (!DateTime.TryParseExact(datestring, "yyyyMMdd", 
                            null, DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal, 
                            out dateResult))
    dateResult = DateTime.MinValue; //handle failed conversion here
```

Comment: @Dorababu, added two examples.

Comment: But i am getting in the format dd/mm/yy and i need not want timestamp

Comment: Is that your local standard for formatting? You can use the .ToString() from the datetime value to change the output format.

Comment: see this link for DateTime formatting => http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If C#/.NET, use [`DateTime.Parse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1k1skd40.aspx). If Java, use [`DateFormat.parse`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#parse(java.lang.String))

Comment: NOTE: I'm assuming C# because of the lower-case `string` type. If it's another language, please edit your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

in C/C++, use the time.h (ctime) library's gmtime function, after converting the time to an integer: `tm =gmtime(atoi(time_string));`

Answer (score -2):

use this to convert time

> using System; using System.Collections.Generic; using
>   System.ComponentModel; using System.Data; using System.Drawing; using
>   System.Text; using System.Windows.Forms;
>
> namespace DateTimeConvert {
>       public partial class Form1 : Form
>       {
>           public Form1()
>           {
>               InitializeComponent();
>           }
>
> ```
>     private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
>     {
>       label1.Text= ConvDate_as_str(textBox1.Text);
>     }
>
>     public string ConvDate_as_str(string dateFormat)
>     {
>         try
>         {
>             char[] ch = dateFormat.ToCharArray();
>             string[] sps = dateFormat.Split(' ');
>             string[] spd = sps[0].Split('.');
>             dateFormat = spd[0] + ":" + spd[1]+" "+sps[1];
>             DateTime dt = new DateTime();
>             dt = Convert.ToDateTime(dateFormat);
>             return dt.Hour.ToString("00") + dt.Minute.ToString("00");
>         }
>         catch (Exception ex)
>         {
>             return "Enter Correct Format like <5.12 pm>";
>         }
>
>     }
>
>
>     private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
>     {
>        label2.Text = ConvDate_as_date(textBox2.Text);
>     }
>
>     public string ConvDate_as_date(string stringFormat)
>     {
>         try
>         {
>             string hour = stringFormat.Substring(0, 2);
>             string min = stringFormat.Substring(2, 2);
>             DateTime dt = new DateTime();
>             dt = Convert.ToDateTime(hour+":"+min);
>             return String.Format("{0:t}", dt); ;
>         }
>         catch (Exception ex)
>         {
>             return "Please Enter Correct format like <0559>";
>         }
>     }
> } }
> ```